# Most efficient way to remove array from multidimensional array

Tags: php, arrays

Consider this array:

```
$userBookmarks = [
    [
        "id": 10000,
        "dateAdded": 1552127606
    ],
    [
        "id": 20000,
        "dateAdded": 1552127610
    ],
    [
        "id": 30000,
        "dateAdded": 1552127614
    ]
]
```

Suppose I know the ID is 10000 and I want to remove the child array where the value of `id` is 10000, what is the most efficient way so I can remove the entire child array and be left with this:

```
$userBookmarks = [
    [
        "id": 20000,
        "dateAdded": 1552127610
    ],
    [
        "id": 30000,
        "dateAdded": 1552127614
    ]
]
```

My "closest" attempt:

```
for( $i = 0; $i < count( $userBookmarks ); $i++ ) {

    $currentBookmark = $userBookmarks[ $i ]; 

    if( $currentBookmark['id'] == $newBookmarkID ) {
        unset( $currentBookmark ); 
        break; 
    } else {
        $userBookmarks[] = $newBookmark; 
    }

}
```

But it's really not doing anything...

Comment: You need to loop over each array element and check if id = x and then delete the element. it is O(n) and efficient.

Comment: Yes, the `id` values are unique. I did try a few things with loops and `unset` but I'm very new to arrays and can't make it work. I also researched but all questions seem to be about deleting elements inside arrays, not the arrays themselves.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simple thing to fix.

You need to `unset()` the original reference to the subarray.

Change:

```
unset( $currentBookmark );
```

to:

```
unset( $userBookmarks[ $i ] );
```

---

The "functional" alternative would look like this:

```
$userBookmarks = [
    ["id" => 10000, "dateAdded" => 1552127606],
    ["id" => 20000, "dateAdded" => 1552127610],
    ["id" => 30000, "dateAdded" => 1552127614]
];

$newBookmarkID = 10000;

$userBookmarks = array_filter($userBookmarks, function ($v) use ($newBookmarkID) {
        return $v['id'] != $newBookmarkID;
    });

var_export($userBookmarks);
```

Demonstration: https://3v4l.org/uhDB2